# Are css 3d transforms fully suported on android > 3.0?

Tags: android, css, css-transforms

According to caniuse.com Android fully supports css 3d transforms. But it seems that "preserve-3d" is not supported. (I can only test it via Browserstack.)

Watch this 3d Cube experiment on android:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/demos/detail/simple-css3-3d-cube/launch

or this simple example:
http://unformedbuilding.com/demo/2012/css-transforms/3d/3d-transform-style.html

Why does it not work?
Is there a reliable test for support of "preserve-3d" on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. A very good and well exmplaned list of css support on most devices can be found here:

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d)

Comment: But why then do these simple examples not work in the android emulators at browserstack?

Comment: my general experience is that emulators usually doesn't work like the devices they should emulate :D best practice is allways to proove on the devices you are developing for. of course it'S not always possible :(